# Cannot read params in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I started to have a problem with react-router, I cannot read the parameters for it:

This is the code:

```
 function App() {

const matchSample = useRouteMatch("/test/:id");

let { id } = useParams();

console.log("id", id);

return (
    <>
        {matchSample && <Home />}
    </>
)


 }

   const _ = withRouter (App);
   export { App };
```

My app already has the router at the base:

```
     <React.Fragment >
        <CssBaseline />
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <App />
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
```

I am not sure if I need to add withRouter as wrapper for my function, but even with or without the result is the same: undefined.

Comment: You need only one route?

Comment: No, I need more routes. This is just a sample for simplification.

Comment: Do you have routes defined like <Router> 
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
</Router> or something like this?

Comment: I do not. Is not the point of this "{matchSample && <Home />}" to replace the Switch? This is what I thought.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Switch is mandatory in order to be able to propagate the props. If Switch is not provided then the useParams and rest cannot work.

If anyone knows an option not to use Switch but make useParams working do let me know please.. till then I have to add Switch back.